# How to log something from a java component to the Mule log file?

Tags: java, mule, mule-component, anypoint-studio

Why I do not see the errors that are happening in a java component in Mule log file? Moreover lets say I have system.out.print in the java, how can I see the output in the log file?

Comment: What does the documentation say? https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/logging-in-mule? Did you try some prior research? For things going to system.out ... I doubt that they show up in any log file; unless you manage to put some code in place that forcefully changes where System.out is going to.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are writing your own Java Component that implements callable.

To write something in the Logs from within a Java Component you need to get a logger such as :

```
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyCallableClass.class);
```

see https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-hello-world-example/

Then from within your functions you can create a log entry, such as:

```
logger.error("This is an example of a log entry with Error Level.");
```

For your other question , unless you are using a try catch block within your component the exceptions thrown within your component should be propagated to the mule flow, however in the Mule Logs you would also see that the exception was caused by a Java Component.

I would suggest that you attach more information on what your Java component is doing, together with logs so we would be able to understand better what you are experiencing.

That said, I created a quick example (see below) to help you out. When you run and hit the http endpoint you should see a message printed in the logger as error from within the component, then a custom exception is thrown and it is catched within the catch exception strategy block that matches our expression   :

**Flow:**

```
<flow name="flow-that-calls-component-with-exception">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8089" doc:name="HTTP" />
        <component class="com.example.MyCallableClass" doc:name="Java" />

        <choice-exception-strategy>

            <catch-exception-strategy when="exception.causedBy(com.example.MyCustomException)">
                <logger level="ERROR" message="My Custom Exception was thrown" />
                <set-payload value="My Custom Exception was thrown." />
            </catch-exception-strategy>

            <catch-exception-strategy>
                <logger level="ERROR" message="Another exception was thrown" />
                <set-payload value="Another exception was thrown." />
            </catch-exception-strategy>

        </choice-exception-strategy>
    </flow>
```

Java Component:

```
package com.example;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.mule.api.MuleEventContext;
import org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable;

public class MyCallableClass implements Callable {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyCallableClass.class);

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {

        logger.error("This is an example of a log entry with Error Level.");
        //Our Java component will throw an exception so that we can see that we can catch it in a flow
        throw new MyCustomException();
        // throw new Exception("This is an exception that will be thrown in a flow");
        // return eventContext.getMessage().getPayload();
    }

}
```

Custom Exception:

```
package com.example;

public class MyCustomException extends Exception {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5738957517051661541L;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push data to the STDIN/OUT. The connector allows you to write data in and out of JAVA System streams for debugging. This is not recommended in production.

[This URL](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/stdio-transport-reference) has information and a sample.

In a real world scenario ,  you would need to configure a logger package to manage the logging. This can be for example [log4j2](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/logging-in-mule) that is used in mule